# UIWebView no abre URL cuando iniciado por botón

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview

Necesito hacer que mi app abra una URL cuando el usuario toca un botón en especifico, por ejemplo: tenemos 4 botones: botón 1, botón 2, botón 3 y botón 4. Botón 1 abre google.com y botón 2 abre facebook.com, necesito que cuando el usuario le dé a botón 1 se abra google. El problema es se realiza el "Segue" hacia el WebView, pero el WebView se queda en blanco y no carga el URL.

```
// ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



// Variables and Contants
let WebViewSegue = "WebViewSegue"
var facebookButtonPressed = false
var twitterButtonPressed = false
var instagramButtonPressed = false
var pinterestButtonPressed = false
var flickrButtonPressed = false
var linkedinButtonPressed = false
var youtubeButtonPressed = false
var vimeoButtonPressed = false



// Initializations
@IBOutlet weak var mainWebView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var loadingView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var facebookButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var twitterButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var instagranButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var pinterestButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var flickrButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var linkedinButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var youtubeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var vimeoButton: UIButton!



// Social Media Buttons Actions and Functions
/**************************************************************************************************************************/
@IBAction func facebookButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // Perform Segue
    performSegue(withIdentifier: WebViewSegue, sender: nil)

    // Change Boolean
    facebookButtonPressed = true

    // Load Facebook
    loadFacebook()

    // Detect Loading
    detectLoadingStatus()
}


@IBAction func twitterButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // Perform Segue
    performSegue(withIdentifier: WebViewSegue, sender: nil)

    // Change Boolean
    twitterButtonPressed = true

    // Load Twitter
    loadTwitter()

    // Detect Loading
    detectLoadingStatus()
}


@IBAction func instagramButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // Perform Segue
    performSegue(withIdentifier: WebViewSegue, sender: nil)

    // Change Boolean
    instagramButtonPressed = true

    // Load Instagram
    loadInstagram()

    // Detect Loading
    detectLoadingStatus()
}


@IBAction func pinterestButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // Perform Segue
    performSegue(withIdentifier: WebViewSegue, sender: nil)

    // Change Boolean
    pinterestButtonPressed = true

    // Load Pinterest
    loadPinterest()

    // Detect Loading
    detectLoadingStatus()
}


@IBAction func flickrButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // Perform Segue
    performSegue(withIdentifier: WebViewSegue, sender: nil)

    // Change Boolean
    flickrButtonPressed = true

    // Load Flickr
    loadFlickr()

    // Detect Loading
    detectLoadingStatus()
}


@IBAction func linkedinButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // Perform Segue
    performSegue(withIdentifier: WebViewSegue, sender: nil)

    // Change Boolean
    linkedinButtonPressed = true

    // Load LinkedIn
    loadLinkedin()

    // Detect Loading
    detectLoadingStatus()
}


@IBAction func youtubeButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // Perform Segue
    performSegue(withIdentifier: WebViewSegue, sender: nil)

    // Change Boolean
    youtubeButtonPressed = true

    // Load YouTube
    loadYouTube()

    // Detect Loading
    detectLoadingStatus()
}


@IBAction func vimeoButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // Perform Segue
    performSegue(withIdentifier: WebViewSegue, sender: nil)

    // Change Boolean
    vimeoButtonPressed = true

    // Load Vimeo
    loadVimeo()

    // Detect Loading
    detectLoadingStatus()
}



// Tab Bar Buttons Functions
/**************************************************************************************************************************/
@IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    resetButtons()
}

@IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
    mainWebView.goBack()
}

@IBAction func reloadButton(_ sender: Any) {
    mainWebView.reload()
}

@IBAction func forwardButton(_ sender: Any) {
    mainWebView.goForward()
}


// Load WebViews Functions
/**************************************************************************************************************************/
public func loadFacebook(){
    // Load URL
    mainWebView?.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://m.facebook.com")!))

    // Confirm Load
    print("Loading Facebook...")
}


public func loadTwitter() {
    // Load URL
    mainWebView?.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://mobile.twitter.com")!))

    // Confirm Load
    print("Loading Twitter...")
}


public func loadInstagram() {
    // Load URL
    mainWebView?.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://instagram.com")!))

    // Confirm Load
    print("Loading Instagram...")
}


public func loadPinterest(){
    // Load URL
    mainWebView?.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://pinterest.com")!))

    // Confirm Load
    print("Loading Pinterest...")
}


public func loadFlickr() {
    // Load URL
    mainWebView?.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://flickr.com")!))

    // Confirm Load
    print("Loading Flickr...")
}


public func loadLinkedin() {
    // Load URL
    mainWebView?.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://linkedin.com")!))

    // Confirm Load
    print("Loading LinkedIn...")
}


public func loadYouTube() {
    // Load URL
    mainWebView?.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://m.youtube.com")!))

    // Confirm Load
    print("Loading YouTube...")
}


public func loadVimeo() {
    // Load URL
    mainWebView?.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://vimeo.com")!))

    // Confirm Load
    print("Loading Vimeo...")
}


// Reset Buttons
/**************************************************************************************************************************/
public func resetButtons() {
    facebookButtonPressed = false
    twitterButtonPressed = false
    instagramButtonPressed = false
    pinterestButtonPressed = false
    flickrButtonPressed = false
    linkedinButtonPressed = false
    youtubeButtonPressed = false
    vimeoButtonPressed = false

    print("All buttons rested!")
}



// Loading Status
/**************************************************************************************************************************/
public func detectLoadingStatus() {
    while mainWebView?.isLoading == true {
        loadingView.isHidden = false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: y como configuras los botones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace falta un tanto de más de contexto para saber exactamente lo que está sucediendo. Sin embargo, por lo que se puede ver en el código, el `WebView` y los botones están en el mismo `UIViewController`, por lo que no es necesario llamar el `performSegue` en los `IBAction` de los botones.

Sospecho que tu problema se solucionaría borrando los `performSegue`.

Te comparto una solución que usa `performSegue` para moverse a otro controlador. 
El storyboard se ve así:

[image: storyboard de la aplicación]

La aplicación consta de 3 `UIViewController`. El primero (de izquierda a derecha) es un `UINavigationController` que basicamente es la barra de navegación. El segundo (llamado muy originalmente `ViewController`) únicamente contiene los botones, mientras que el tercero (llamado `WebViewViewController`) contiene un `UIWebView` de toda la pantalla.

EL código de `ViewController` se ve así:

```
import UIKit

enum link {
    case google
    case facebook
    case instagram
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate var seleccionado : link?
    let webViewSegue = "WebViewSegue"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == self.webViewSegue {

            if let webViewVC =  segue.destination as? WebViewViewController {
                webViewVC.linkParaAbrir = self.seleccionado
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func googlePresionado(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.seleccionado = .google
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: webViewSegue, sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func facebookPresionado(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.seleccionado = .facebook
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: webViewSegue, sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func InstagramPresionado(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.seleccionado = .instagram
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: webViewSegue, sender: self)
    }
}
```

Se crea un `enum` con las opciones de links que pueden existir (por simplicidad lo reduje a 3), cada botón tiene su `IBAction` cuyo comportamiento es fijar una variable de clase y ejecutar el `segue` a `WebViewViewController`.

El código de `WebViewViewController` se ve así:

```
import UIKit

class WebViewViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    var linkParaAbrir : link!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.abrirLink()
    }

    private func abrirLink() {

        let link: String
        switch linkParaAbrir! {
        case .google:
            link = "https://www.google.com"
        case .facebook:
            link = "https://www.facebook.com"
        case .instagram:
            link = "https://www.instagram.com"
        }

        if let url = URL(string: link) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.loadRequest(request)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Aquí lo que se hace es que en el método `viewDidLoad` dependiendo del parámetro se regresa el url correspondiente al botón seleccionado y se carga el URL mediante el `UIWebView`.

La aplicación se ve así:

[image: Gif con el comportamiento de la aplicación]

Comment: Gracias! Me funcionó a la perfección!!!